# Maven release avoid huge repository checkout

Tags: maven, svn, branch, maven-release-plugin

I try to release a maven project to the new version.

Therefore I use

> mvn release:prepare release:perform

To release that version is not a big deal. Unfortunately it is a big project and have more than 700 releases in the past. Every release have its own tag.

Example:

```
repo 
 + branches
 + tags
    + project-1.0.0
    + project-1.0.1
    + project-1.0.2
    + project-1.0.3
         (...)
    + project-7.9.2
 + trunk
    + src
    + pom.xml
```

Using the release-plugin it download all the tags making it about `190 GB` of code and old tags.

This is a problem because it takes a hours to checkout all the tags.

I can not simply "remove old tags". This will make the `release:prepare release:perform` brake the release-process having the message:

```
[INFO] de.e_nexus.projekt.xdiff ........................... SKIPPED ?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ?
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE    ?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ?
[INFO] Total time: 05:52 min (Wall Clock)   ?
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-10T22:23:19+01:00   ?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ?
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project projekt: Unable to tag SCM  ?
[ERROR] Provider message:   ?
[ERROR] The svn tag command failed. ?
[ERROR] Command output: ?
[ERROR] svn: E160013: File not found: revision 3861, path '/repo/tags/projekt-1.0.0'    ?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1] ?
[ERROR] ?
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. ?
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.  ?
[ERROR] ?
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:   ?
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

---

How to get rid of old tags **AND** be able to release using mavens release plugin?

Comment: If you try to checkout root of your project your configutation is simply wrong. You should only checkout `/trunk` instead ....That means your scm connection parts not configured correctly...(or other things?)

Comment: @khmarbaise If I should only checkout trunk only, how is the release-process capable of creating release-tags? How can you tell the error-message pointing out of trunk-folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out only the trunk of your project. You don't need to checkout all your tags and branches to create a new tag out of trunk.

> If I should only checkout trunk only, how is the release-process capable of creating release-tags? How can you tell the error-message pointing out of trunk-folder?

Maven uses a Subversion client to create a new tag in the repository. This does not require all the tags to be present on the client side. Check examples in [SVNBook | Tags](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/tags/). The examples show that you can create a 'URL to URL' tag (no working copy at all) or a 'working copy to URL' tag (tagging the current state of the working copy). No need to have the all the tags locally.

Additional examples are also available in [SVNBook | `svn copy`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/copy/).

Since tagging is a very common operation, I'm sure that Maven knows how to do it properly. But you need to examine and fix your configuration.

PS Great multi-display setup in your profile @Grim!

Comment: Indeed, I had to check "Only the SVN trunk, without tags and branches!" in the "releasemanager". And I must not remove old tags. Anyway: I have no idea why I cant remove old tags, so I have no idea why the error-message from the question exists. But to checkout only trunk solved everything for some reason.